# Is it Possible to ignore inner class name and variable while Converting java to Json

Tags: java, json

I am trying to  create a json where outer class object has all inner class's fields but i don't want the object of inner class in the json.

I tried this:

```
public class College {
    Student student;

    class Student {
        int id;
        String name;
    }
}
```

Actual Result:

```
{
  "college" {
      "student" {
          "id" : "",
          "name" : ""
      }
  }
}
```

Expectation:

```
{
  "college" {
      "id" : "",
      "name" : ""
  }
}
```

Comment: your `actual result` and `Expection` is not even a correct JSON

Comment: I do not see any **inner class** here, maybe you are confusing terms. Why not just serialize the `student` instead of the `college`, that sounds like what you want. Also, what if a college has multiple students?

Answer (score 1):

Well, It does not look like the correct json.
If you are using the jackson library, use the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation

If you want results similar to what you expected ...like below:

#### Colleage class:

```java
class College {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Student student;

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
}
```

#### Student class:

```java
class Student {
    String id;
    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### Test code:

```
class JacksonTest {
    @Test
    public void objToJsonTest() {
        Student student = new Student();
        College college = new College();
        college.setStudent(student);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

        String s = null;
        try {
            s = mapper.writeValueAsString(college);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        // print json format string
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

#### Result:

> {"College":{"id":"","name":""}}

#### without `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation:

> {"College":{"student":{"id":"","name":""}}}